# Checking where the file is stored in android?

Tags: android, file

I am writing a log data to the File in android. But I am unable to understand where this file is stored on my android device ( google nexsus 7 ). Where and How should I look for the contents of the file ?

Following is the piece of code I am using to write log data to the file.

```
public File AppendingLog(String LogData){


        try {
            File logFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "yourLog.txt");
            if (!logFile.exists()) {
                try {
                    logFile.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            try {
                BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile,
                        true));
                buf.append(LogData);
                buf.newLine();
                buf.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return logFile;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

android.util.Log.d("myapp", logFile.toString());

Answer (score 1):

On most devices, it will be in `/sdcard/`. The exact path will be `/sdcard/yourLog.txt`.

As you are using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`, the actual path will differ between devices. Some devices return the *external* sd card path, but most will return the *internal* sd card's path, which usually is `/sdcard/`.

Answer (score 0):

I think answers below are what you need.
You can also download Astro File Manager App which will also give you an idea where your files go on Android System.